# Inside the horizontal StackView the labels are cutoff edges when it stretched to smaller screens. How to solve this?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This is the problem
In larger screens it okey but when display in smaller screens the labels are getting compressed. And show ... in right end side of the label.
I want to solve the case of Labels only. I put my screenshot below. **never mind the buttons I want only Labels**.
[one is my iPhone 5s and I create the view in iPhone 7 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkFzI.png)

Comment: You should not expect others on this site to be able to answer your question with knowing anything about your code. Please edit your question and add the relevant code in code blocks to your question.

Comment: Its not code based its only based on UIBuilder, so I can't post codes. But I post screenshot of it you can click that link which emphasis in blue colour.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the right side of the photo before when I clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale the font size for the label so it will adjust with the screen size.

In interface builder, click on the label, and look for the Autoshrink section. There you can set a "Minimum Font Scale" or "Minimum Font Size". The default is "Fixed Font Size", so it won't adjust.

[image]